# Electrical plug question

Tags: electrical

I have a dust collector that has a 6-15 plug. I want to occasionally be able to plug a heater into that receptacle that requires a 6-30. Can I change the dust collector 6-15 to a 6-30?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you changing the receptacle in the wall, or the plug on the end of the dust collector cord?

Comment: What is the current rating of the breaker? What is the size of the wire? If the wire is #14 or #12 copper you cannot change the receptacle, but if you have #10 wire and a 30-A breaker, then you could change the receptacle to a 6-30. Look to see what you have; maybe someone looked to the future. Is this the only receptacle on this breaker?

Comment: Is running another circuit for the dust collector not an option?

Answer (score 4):

You can't / shouldn't try to make an adapter to power a 6-30 device from a 6-15 receptacle, the voltage is correct but the current handling capacity is insufficient.  The 6-30 heater would at a minimum overload the 6-15 receptacle, and likely overload the circuit's wiring and breaker.  Hopefully the breaker would trip before much damage was done, and you'd only waste time, but if the breaker doesn't trip quickly, you could start a fire.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Given the 6-15 or 6-20 receptacle (15A or 20A), the wiring would be be #14 or #12, and will be inadequate for a heater that needs a 6-30 receptacle.  It will trip the 15A or 20A breaker that is correct for #14 or #12 wire/cable, respectively.

A -30 (30A) receptacle can only be on a 30A circuit.  A 30A circuit requires #10 cable.

If you have the breaker spaces, add a circuit.  If you don't, then install a subpanel in the garage, run the fattest cable you can to the subpanel, and fork off whichever circuits you need. Remember to go big on the subpanel, as each circuit will take 2 spaces and you can no longer use "double-stuff" breakers.